# how to impersonate in linux

Tags: python, linux, impersonation, rhel

I have developed a multi-platform desktop application in python and PyQt and in it i want to implement the concept of impersonation. I have a requirement where user selects a file and the the application will check for naming conventions and other things. If everythin is fine then it copies the file in a server where only impersonate user lets say (user123) has full permissions other has only read permissions.

I could able to achieve this in windows by using `win32security` and `win32con`

**TO IMPERSONATE LOGIN**

```
Self.handel=win32security.LogonUser(self.loginID,self.domain,self.password,win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,win32con.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
win32security.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(self.handel)
```

**AND TO REVERT BACK TO USER**

```
win32security.RevertToSelf()
```

Can anyone suggest an approach to this under Linux (RHEL 6).

Answer (score 1):

First, think whether your task actually needs OS-level impersonation.

- If you use e.g. PySmbClient to access a Windows file share, then you manage all connections yourself and you can just give different credentials to smbclient.
- If you use PyKDE4.kio, as far as I know the same applies (KIO uses smbclient).
- If you access the file server over an existing system-level mount, there is no actual "impersonation" as in Windows; it is done by simply changing the process' ["effective UID"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and generally can be done only if the program has *root* privileges (or the root-equivalent CAP_SETUID privilege on Linux).

  ```
  uid = pw.getpwnam(username).pw_uid

  os.seteuid(uid)
  ...
  os.seteuid(0)
  ```

  (This is not guaranteed to work with network filesystems that store credentials in kernel keyrings... I don't yet have an answer for that.)
- However, most desktop programs do not have root privileges (and **should not** have them). In that case, seteuid() is unavailable, and privileged actions are normally done by a privileged daemon that the desktop app contacts using some form of IPC (usually D-Bus).